# Swift: Join method using parameter of type Array<Character> or Slice<Character> crashes in Release configuration

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have the following (simplified) code in Swift which works perfectly well in Debug configuration:

```
import Foundation

let charSlice = Array("Any string at all")
println( charSlice )
let str1 = "".join(charSlice.map{"\($0)"})
println (str1)
```

This produces the following output (as expected):

```
[A, n, y,  , s, t, r, i, n, g,  , a, t,  , a, l, l]
Any string at all
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

If I then change the Build Configuration to Release Mode I get a Run Time Error:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

in the call to `"".join`

Am I doing something wrong or is this worth reporting as a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Testing on XCode Beta 6]

This seems to be a bug in the optimized code generated by the compiler in the Release mode. If you change the Release mode optimization level to None (Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Optimization Level), the issue goes away.

Interestingly, `.join()` doesn't fail for null and empty strings, I assume because the method checks for them specifically as a performance optimization.

```
var baseString = ","
baseString.join([])    // works
baseString.join([""])  // works
baseString.join(["a"]) // fails
```

Feel free to report this as a bug.